# Why do we use "have" with does and not "has"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

**Does** and **has** both are used with singular pronouns (*He has the bottle **,** He does play cricket **,*** etc) whereas **Do** and **have** are used with plural pronouns ( *They have the bottle* **,** *Do they like cricket?* **,** etc)

But still we use **Does** with **have** ( *She does have a car* ). Why? Shouldn't it be

> She **does has** a car.

Comment: You realize that "He does (not) *play*..." and "She does *have*..." is the same grammatical structure? "have" being used not as an auxillary, but as simple verb in infinitive?

Comment: That is the question, Why "_He does play..._" and "_She does have ..._" are grammatically same? more importantly why "_She does have ..._" is even grammatically correct? Shouldn't it be "_She does has.._" ?

Comment: Because **do** is used as an auxuliary, and in its form **does** it already bears the "third-person-singular" marking (the letter **s** at the end). Any verb that connects to an auxiliary has no need for bearing the same "third-person-singular" marking. This is why we say "She play**s**" but "She doe**s** play" (no **s** on "play" in this latter case; the word "doe**s**" already does this job, there's no need to duplicate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to realize that a verb can be either

- [finite](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_verb) (= matches the number of the subject of the sentence) or
- [nonfinite](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_verb) (= no inflection), which are infinitive, participles and gerunds. We are dealing with infinitives in your examples.

For an independent clause (AKA "sentence") you need ***at least*** one finite verb and unless you are making a "list" ("She *laughs* and *sings* and *dances*.") you use ***only*** one finite verb. In your example sentences you use four finite verbs, *do*, *play*, *like* and *have*.

Very simple sentences use only one verb, which by definition must be finite.:

> He has the bottle.
>   They have the bottle

For questions or special emphasis you use an [auxiliary verb](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auxiliary_verb) (-> finite) together with a verb in the [infinitive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive):

> He does play cricket.
>    Do they like cricket?

So yes, in these cases "do" becomes "does" for third person singular because it is finite.

Comment: What Ritwik seemingly wants to know is why we can't have constructions like "She does has a car.", with both **does** and **has** in the third-person-singular form. I've edited Ritwik's question to make it clearer, based on their comment.

Comment: @CopperKettle That's why I wrote "finite + infinitive"... You think that's unclear? Any suggestions....? I made a small edit - better?

Comment: Yes, better: "only one finite verb". I remember in our school textbooks we had pictures of a train with two carriages, one "finite" and another, attached to it, "non-finite" (the carriages had words on them). Of course no  suchlike recondite terminology was used, but it made clear that only the "helping verb" will assume the 3rd person singular form. (0:

Answer (score 1):

"to do" is not only used in questions and negations, but also for emphasizing a verb.

You can say "I love it" and you can stress your statement by saying " I do love it".

"to do" is used in contradictions as in

- You don't know it. - Contradiction: Yes, I do.
- I think he doesn't have a car. -Contradiction: Yes, he does (have a car).

Comment: apart from the last line, I am still trying to figure out how your answer is related to the question?

Comment: @Ritwik : Because the question was significantly edited after the answer was posted - only then the *real* issue of the question became clear. The upvote is justified with regard to the original phrasing, IMHO.